# Function argements: pass standard collection by reference or iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, arguments, c++14, pass-by-reference

When passing a standard collection(such as `std::string` or `std::vector<std::string>`) as a function argument, is it to better pass the collection by reference or via iterators?

A reference to the Collection is one argument only, while two args would be required for both `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, because it's not easy to elegantly discern the end of a collection from just `std::begin()`.

However, much of the standard library opts for iterators over a collection reference, so I'm wondering if the answer is less than straightforward?

Is there a good, objective reason to prefer one form over the other?

Comment: The standard library does that in order to separate algorithms from containers and to allow arbitrary iterator types (including plain old pointers). Would that be useful in your case?

Comment: In my case, in the function body, the collection is stepped through via built-in iterators provided by the collection.  Does this mean its better to pass a single argument( by reference ) ?

Comment: It's cleaner that way, yes. You might prefer the range idiom if you don't know the type of collection you'll be working with (for instance, if you might want to use a C array), or if you might work with a subset of the collection, or in a couple of other cases. But it makes for uglier code, IMO, so you don't want to do it unless you need the flexibility it gives you.